# How to dismiss View Controller from another

Tags: swift, firebase, navigation

So I have three `ViewControllers`: A, B and C. I have a listener from **firebase** in `ViewController` B which when activated, if you are currently in `ViewController` C, it should dismiss `ViewController` C. However, if you are in `ViewController` B, it should not dismiss back to `ViewController` A. The code I have so far is:

```
 self.parentViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

which is in the listener of `ViewController` B. The problem I have with this is that if i'm in `ViewController` B, it dismisses it.  What should I add to this *code* (like an `if` statement of some sort) to check that if the user is currently in `ViewController` C on his device, then dismiss that, otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: turn off listener when you are in that view controller

Comment: You can try setting a variable to some value if you are in a specific view controller and only call the above code when that variable has a specific value.

Comment: In a nutshell, what you are saying is that view B is observing Firebase. If the user is in view C and view B received an event, view C should close. If they are in view B or view A, do nothing. Correct?

Comment: Yes sir Jay, that is correct, i still havent found a method that says something like ("if you are currently in this view controller, then dismiss..."

Comment: How about having the three view controllers instantiated in your AppDelegate or maybe a master view controller. Track which viewController is the active one - that can be done in a lot of ways but the simplest is to just flag a appDelegate variable in prepareToSegue. Any time you segue from one to another, update the variable. Then you always know which one the user is in. Then when you receive a Firebase event, poll the variable to see where the use UIViewController and if activeViewControlller = C then close it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
if(self.parentViewController?.isKindOfClass(ClassToDismiss){}
```

Comment: hi, that "sort of" worked but created a lot of bugs. Im thinking of steering away from using parent View Controller and try something else like, an if statement that says, if im currently in this view controller, then dismiss, else do nothing.

Comment: or maybe since view controller b is presenting view controller c, is there something like, if view controller c was presented by B, then do this, if not... just spitballing ideas, not sure whats correct.

Comment: Maybe if you have a variable that holds the previous view controller: 

var previousViewController = UIViewController(), so in the ViewController where you present the other, do viewcontroller.previousViewController = self.